# Why won't my checkmarks render as selected when page loads?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I posted a simpler version of this, but realized I needed to share more code to find the problem.  So here's the rest. I have a component, with a default state as empty, it passes through to a child component where you answer the questions as Yes or No, and then it sets the state to that answer.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isBoxChecked: " ",
        };
        this.handleCheck = this.handleCheck.bind(this);
        this.handleChangek = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }
```

This is the check handler and change handler(it changes the state value to either "Yes" or "No", and makes an API call to store it in the database, and this part works fine):

```
handleCheck(e) {
    this.setState(({ isChecked }) => ({
      isChecked: !isChecked,
    }));
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.checked }, () => this.updateDB());
  }

handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value }, () => this.updateDB());
    };
```

Here's my child component is called which has the question:

```
<PersonnelFiles
       handleChange={this.handleChange}
       handleCheck={this.handleCheck}
    {...this.state}
 />
```

And this is my child components code(when I click an answer, it does turn on, and does save the answer in the database):

```
<Form.Group
                                    className="ml-3"
                                    name="formIsBoxChecked"
                                    as={Row}
                                    controlId="formIsBoxChecked"
                                    onChange={this.props.handleChange}
                                    >
                                        <Form.Label column sm={5}>
                                            1. Select Yes or No:
                                        </Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Check
                                            inline
                                            type="radio"
                                            label="Yes"
                                            value="yes"
                                            name="formIsBoxChecked"
                                            id="formIsBoxChecked-Yes"
                                            defaultChecked={
                                            this.props.formIsBoxChecked === "yes"
                                            }
                                        />
                                        <Form.Check
                                            inline
                                            type="radio"
                                            label="No"
                                            value="no"
                                            name="formIsBoxChecked"
                                            id="formIsBoxChecked-No"
                                            defaultChecked={
                                            this.props.formIsBoxChecked === "no"
                                            }                               
                                        />
                                        
                                </Form.Group>
```

However, when I reload the page, an API call does retrieve the values from the database, and setState to change the empty string to the correct answer.  But the box that should be checked does not render as checked, unless I turn the component off and back on again.  Why would this be?  I'm doing text area's the same way and they work as expected.  But radio buttons and checkboxes do not.

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.grabTableData(tableName);
    }

async grabTableData (tableName) {
    await fetch(API_URL + `/${tableName}/${this.props.Id}`)
      .then((res) => {
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw new Error();
        }
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((result) => {
        this.setState({
          ...result[0],
        });
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

As I said, that does grab the data and set the states correctly, it just doesn't then update the radio buttons or checkboxes as expected unless I manually turn the rendering of the component off and on manually.  I'm doing that when  button click.